# Dynamic text box value doesn't capture in validation - PHP

Tags: php

foremost apologies if the following code is a bit lengthy one but I guess I have to put it up for you to see the functionality.

My issue is when `Save` button is clicked, irrespective of whether the text boxes have a value or empty, it always print the message `Saved!`. Simply it doesn't validate the text box for a value. Can some one pls tell me where have I gone wrong in this. Thank you.

```
<?php 
SESSION_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userLogin']))
{
header('Location:../2-lo');
}


include ("../connection/index.php"); 

?>
<?php
    function putForm2(){
    $myForm = "<form name='form2' method='post' action=''><table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!<br></td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' name='txt123' id='txt123'></td></tr> <tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></td></tr></table></form>";
    return $myForm;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="One">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="#">

<?php
$SQLbrands="SELECT * FROM brands";
$runBrands=mysqli_query($db, $SQLbrands) or die ("SQL Error");
$noRow=mysqli_num_rows($runBrands);


$brndTable = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' id='brndTable1' class='brndTable1'>";
$brndTable .= "<thead><tr><th class='brT11'>Brand Name</th><th class='brT21'>Variant</th><th class='brT31'>SKU</th>
                      <th class='brT41'></th></tr></thead>";
$brndTable .= "<tbody>";
while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
{
    $wec = $reK['id']; $wec2 = $reK['bvariant']; $wec3 = $reK['bsku'];
    $brndTable .= "<tbody class='colormine'><tr>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT1'>".$reK["bname"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT2'>".$reK["bvariant"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT3'>".$reK["bsku"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT4'><input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='$wec' ></td>";
    $brndTable .= "</tr>";
}
$brndTable .= "</tbody>";
$brndTable .= "</table>";


echo $brndTable;
?>

              <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="two">


            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
            {   if(!isset($_POST['delz']))
                {echo 'No check boxes are selected!'; return;} else 
                {
                $mohan = "<form method='post' action=''><table border='1' id='myTad'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
                    <tr class='tabColor'>
                    <td>Brands</td>
                    <td>Scheme</td>
                    <td>Allocation</td>
                    <td>Focus Channels</td>
                    <td>Focus Provinces</td>
                    </tr>";
                foreach($_POST['delz'] as $delz)
                            {
                                $delz=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$delz);
                                $QR = "SELECT bname, bvariant, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$delz'";
                                $rr = mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
                                $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);
                                $rr = $rr->fetch_assoc();

                                $mohan .= "<tr class='sc_eght' ><td class='sc_five'>".$rr['bname']." ".$rr['bvariant']." ".$rr['bsku'];
                                $mohan .="</td>
                                   <td><textarea  style='width:80px;' name='schema[]' id='vtext' class='sc_one' rows='1' cols='1' maxlength='100'></textarea></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='allocas[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two' size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='channelz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_three' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='provinz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_four' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                                   </tr>";

                            }
                                $mohan .= "<input type='submit' name='sendMe' id='sendMe' value='Save'></table></form>";
                                $_SESSION['cb'] = $mohan; }

                                if(isset($_SESSION['cb'])) 
                                echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
            }   


if(isset($_POST['sendMe']))
{
   if($_POST['provinz'] == "")
    {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Province is empty!"; return;} else   { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

    if(!isset($_POST['allocas']) || $_POST['allocas'] == '')
    {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Allocation is empty!"; return;} else   { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

}

            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see small things missing:

You forgot to concatenate the variable here:
`<input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='$wec' >`

it should be

```
`<input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='".$wec."' />`
```

or

```
`<input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='{$wec}' />`
```

Comment: thanks for the post. But I get this.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\docs\add_invoice\testmm.php on line 54

Comment: one more thing on your while loop, check answer

Comment: Try then <input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='{$wec}' />

Comment: Nope! then, when the 'OneClick' button is submitted it does identified as no check boxes are selected.

Comment: John what have you changed so far? I just noticed the name='delz[]' is no variable (ofcourse) so I edited my answer without concatenating it.

Comment: On your first point i tried both options, didn't work. didn't work means no help to get the desired output as in my question. On the second point if I add == then it gives an error message variable is not defined (variable reK)

Comment: John, i'm tired sorry, ignore the `==` comment, its a while loop, it should be so.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript

```
function validation()  
{
var chks = document.getElementsByName('delz[]');//here delz[] is the name of the textbox

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
    {       
    if (chks[i].value=="")
    {
    alert("Please fillup atleast one textbox");
    chks[i].focus();
    return false;           
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: don't think I can use JS as this happens inside PHP.