# Validating dynamically populated text box fields in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I tried finding an answer to my following issue on an earlier note also but could't.
can some one pls do highlight where have I gone wrong?

My issue is when `Save` button is clicked, irrespective of whether the text boxes have a value or empty, it always print the message Saved!. Simply it doesn't validate the text box for a value.

Also note the text boxes are populated via a loop.

Thank you.

```
<?php 
SESSION_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userLogin']))
{
header('Location:../2-lo');
}


include ("../connection/index.php"); 

?>
<?php
    function putForm2(){
    $myForm = "<form name='form2' method='post' action=''><table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!<br></td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' name='txt123' id='txt123'></td></tr> <tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendtwo' id='sendtwo' value='TwoClick'></td></tr></table></form>";
    return $myForm;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="One">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="#">

<?php
$SQLbrands="SELECT * FROM brands";
$runBrands=mysqli_query($db, $SQLbrands) or die ("SQL Error");
$noRow=mysqli_num_rows($runBrands);


$brndTable = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' id='brndTable1' class='brndTable1'>";
$brndTable .= "<thead><tr><th class='brT11'>Brand Name</th><th class='brT21'>Variant</th><th class='brT31'>SKU</th>
                      <th class='brT41'></th></tr></thead>";
$brndTable .= "<tbody>";
while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
{
    $wec = $reK['id']; $wec2 = $reK['bvariant']; $wec3 = $reK['bsku'];
    $brndTable .= "<tbody class='colormine'><tr>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT1'>".$reK["bname"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT2'>".$reK["bvariant"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT3'>".$reK["bsku"]."</td>";
    $brndTable .= "<td class='brT4'><input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='$wec' ></td>";
    $brndTable .= "</tr>";
}
$brndTable .= "</tbody>";
$brndTable .= "</table>";


echo $brndTable;
?>

              <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="two">


            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
            {   if(!isset($_POST['delz']))
                {echo 'No check boxes are selected!'; return;} else 
                {
                $mohan = "<form method='post' action=''><table border='1' id='myTad'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
                    <tr class='tabColor'>
                    <td>Brands</td>
                    <td>Scheme</td>
                    <td>Allocation</td>
                    <td>Focus Channels</td>
                    <td>Focus Provinces</td>
                    </tr>";
                foreach($_POST['delz'] as $delz)
                            {
                                $delz=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$delz);
                                $QR = "SELECT bname, bvariant, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$delz'";
                                $rr = mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
                                $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);
                                $rr = $rr->fetch_assoc();

                                $mohan .= "<tr class='sc_eght' ><td class='sc_five'>".$rr['bname']." ".$rr['bvariant']." ".$rr['bsku'];
                                $mohan .="</td>
                                   <td><textarea  style='width:80px;' name='schema[]' id='vtext' class='sc_one' rows='1' cols='1' maxlength='100'></textarea></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='allocas[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two' size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='channelz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_three' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='provinz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_four' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                                   </tr>";

                            }
                                $mohan .= "<input type='submit' name='sendMe' id='sendMe' value='Save'></table></form>";
                                $_SESSION['cb'] = $mohan; }

                                if(isset($_SESSION['cb'])) 
                                echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
            }   


if(isset($_POST['sendMe']))
{
   if($_POST['provinz'] == "")
    {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Province is empty!"; return;} else   { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

    if(!isset($_POST['allocas']) || $_POST['allocas'] == '')
    {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Allocation is empty!"; return;} else   { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

}

            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A suggestion, html-php mix is very much confusing, Its better if code is separated php and html, So it is more understandable and debugable.

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamic text box value doesn't capture in validation - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280029/dynamic-text-box-value-doesnt-capture-in-validation-php)

Comment: @CBroe did u read my question here??

Comment: Yes, and it is the same question.

Comment: So why don't you then leave an answer? Lets see if ur a genius

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_POST['allocas']) || $_POST['allocas'] == '')
```

is likely to be your problem line.  This will return true if allocas is either unset or is set but empty.

Perhaps waht you meant was:

```
if(!(isset($_POST['allocas']) || $_POST['allocas'] == ''))
```

Which will return true only if allocas contains text.